# How to include smoothed data line in a plotly 3D plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I'm new to R and even newer to plotly and am using real wind data, collected at 1 Hz with 3D anemometer for 100 minutes, to visualize the data.  I have been able to produce 2D scatter plots with ggplot and then overlay 'smoothed' lines using geom_smooth.
[2D example](https://plot.ly/~shellback3/12)
I have produced a 3D scatter plot with plotly (x = time, y = wind speed, z = wind direction). The data have a lot of variance. [3D plot](https://plot.ly/~shellback3/20)

What I want to do is to display smoothed data in a 3D plot as lines (possibly overlay the point cloud) with x = time, y = smoothed wind speed, and z = smoothed wind direction as lines.

I've spent a lot of time using Google but have not found any examples. As I expected geom_smooth apparently doesn't coexist well with plotly.

ggplot code snippet

```
p4 <- ggplot(upper.ws.df, aes(elapsed.sec, WindDir)) + 
geom_point(colour = "tan", size = 0.25) +
stat_smooth(aes(color = '8'), size = 0.5, method = lm, 
  formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 8), se = FALSE ) +
  # more code
puwdir.smoothed <- ggplotly(p4)
```

plotly 3D code

```
axz <- list(title = 'Direction',
      ticketmode = 'array',
      ticktext = c('E', 'NE', 'N'),
      tickvals = c(0, 2*pi/8, 2*pi/4) )
# Create the plot
p3d.scatter <- plot_ly(upper.ws.df, 
        x = ~elapsed.sec, y = ~WindSpeed, z = ~WindDir,
        type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 0.6, color= ~elapsed.sec, 
        colorscale = list(c(0,'#BA52ED'), c(1,'#FCB040')))
        ) %>%,

  layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = 'Elapsed Time (s)'),
      yaxis = list(title = 'Speed (m/s'),
      zaxis = axz) 
      )

p3d.scatter
```

Comment: ```p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=hp)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "tan", size = 0.25) +
  stat_smooth(aes(color = '8'), size = 0.5, method = lm, 
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 8), se = FALSE );
ggplotly(p)``` this works for me!!

Comment: @M-M Thanks, I've edited my post to indicate that I'm need a 3D plot with the smoothed line.  Sorry.